# $(x+a)^n=x^n+a$ in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z[x]$ then n is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Question

> If $n>1$ is an integer such that $(x+a)^n=x^n+a$ in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z[x]$ for all $a \in \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ then $n$ is prime.

I want to show this with contradiction.

But there are too many cases of prime factorization of composite number.

Could you find me a counterexample for general composite number n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n\gt 1$ be non-prime, and let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$. Suppose that $p^k$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$. We show that $p^k$ does not divide $\binom{n}{p}$, and as a consequence $n$ does not divide $\binom{n}{p}$.

The highest power of $p$ that divides $\frac{n!}{(n-p)!}$ is $p^k$. This is because no integer strictly between $n$ and $n-p$ is divisible by $p$.

It follows that the highest power of $p$ that divides $\frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}$ is $p^{k-1}$. Thus the highest power of $p$ that divides $\binom{n}{p}$ is $p^{k-1}$.

Now consider the polynomial $(x+1)^n$. The coefficient of $x^{n-p}$ is $\binom{n}{p}$, so is non-zero modulo $n$. It follows that the polynomials $(x+1)^n$ and $x^n+1$ are unequal.

Comment: You are welcome.